# Trying to draw flat 3D grid with pygame OpenGL keep getting error 1282 'invalid operation'

Tags: python, opengl, 3d, pygame

I am trying to create a terrain, however I just can't seem to get this grid working? keeps returning this error:

> OpenGL.error.GLError: GLError( err = 1282, description = b'invalid
>   operation', baseOperation = glEnd, cArguments = ()

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
import random

nptx=10
npty=10

def terrain2(): 
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    for ye in range(0,npty):
        for xe in range(0,nptx):
            glVertex3f(xe,ye+1,0)
            glVertex3f(xe+1,ye+1,0)
            glVertex3f(xe+1,ye,0)
            glVertex3f(xe,ye,0)
    glEnd()

def main():
    pygame.init()
    display=(800,600)
    pygame.display.set_mode(display, DOUBLEBUF|OPENGL)

    gluPerspective(45, (display[0]/display[1]),0.1,200)
    glTranslatef(0.0,0.0,-5)

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if pygame.event==pygame.quit():
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
        terrain2()
        pygame.display.flip()
main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the following expression is evaluated

```
if pygame.event==pygame.quit():
```

then the operation [`pygame.quit()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pygame.html#pygame.quit) is executed and all `pygame` modules are uninitialized.

Change it to

```
if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
```

which compares `event.type` to the enum `pygame.QUIT`.